# why do I need to include enctype="multipart/form-data" when sending data through form but don't need when sending through xmlhttprequest

Tags: javascript, html, ajax, forms

When an HTML form contains `<input type="file">` I need to specify the `enctype="multipart/form-data"` attribute on the form. However, when I send a binary file over `XMLHttpRequest` I don't need to specify that type anywhere:

```
var builder = new BlobBuilder();
builder.append("Hello world!");
var blob = builder.getBlob("text/plain");

var oReq = new XMLHttpRequest();
oReq.open("POST", url, true);
oReq.send(blob);
```

Why so?

Comment: `BlobBuilder` has been deprecated for some time, use `var blob = new Blob(['Hello world!'], {type: 'text/plain'});` instead.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

With a form, you are telling the browser how to format the data to send it to the server. (The default value for `enctype` doesn't support files).

With XHR, you are formatting the data yourself. (That said, you **should** still use `addHeader` to specify a suitable content-type for your POST body).

Comment: Thanks. When you say _how to format the data_ - what do you mean? Can you provide a link to an explanation of that? So with XHR I would do it in this way - `oReq.setRequestHeader("content-type", "application/zip")`- if I'm transmitting zipped archive, correct?

Comment: If you are sending a zip file, and not wrapping it in any other data format, then yes, that is the content-type you should use.

Comment: I've just found [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/XMLHttpRequest/Using_XMLHttpRequest#Submitting_forms_and_uploading_files) a good explanation of how encoding affects data represantation in request body. Am I right to assume that if I put content like this `oReq.send("text here")` it will look in request body as though `text/plain` encryption was used?

Comment: It will be encoded as text/plain, but not the text/plain enctype that an HTML form submission would use (which is useless for any real world purpose), and it won't be encrypted at all